# jQuery Sortable plugin on table cells shrink while dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using the [jQuery Sortable UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) to be able to move the rows in a table but I'm having the following problem:

If any of the table cells have data that are not equal in size (which results to an increase or decrease in the width of the cell), the table cells (the tds) shrink while moving a row to a new position. You can see a demonstration [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tUa3w/).

Also, how do I make it so that only when I click in the first column (the empty column at the beginning of the table) of the corresponding row that I should be able to move that row?

Any help please!!!!!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/tUa3w/6/

```
$('.test1 > tbody').sortable({     
    helper: function(event, ui) {
        var myHelper = [];
        myHelper.push('<table style="width: 100%">');
        myHelper.push($(ui).html());
        myHelper.push('</table>');

        return myHelper.join('');
    },
    items: '.item1' 
})
```

What I think is happening is that your helper element had no table to fill out its' width. It's not perfect yet but maybe you can take it from here or someone else can chime in.

Comment: That seems to work, but I can't seem to get what the purpose of the helper element is

Comment: Ok it does not work but I see the idea, I'll try to make it work

Comment: It is working perfectly, mate. It is just I have been looking for. +1

Comment: Dude, your console.log(myHelper); was making it stop working in IE9. It took me the whole morning to spot this problem. :(

Comment: My apologies. Removed the console.log. (Also, we probably shouldn't be leaving console.logs in production code). I had left it in there so the OP could see what was actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/tUa3w/4/

Setting the width of the table to 100% and the td's width to 20% is the simple way. You could set the width of the table to 600px, and each td to 120px.

Use the 'handle' option for the handle.

Comment: Thanks for the "handle" solution, that works but the cells still shrink in the table while dragging.